# Embeded responsive youtube video not shown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, youtube

I'm using bootstrap and I'd like to add some videos from youtube to my website. I've seen [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed) some code to do so, but when I tried it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fermoya/aga395dn/1/) it doesn't work, the video isn't shown.

This is the code:

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIh2xe4jnpk"></iframe>
</div>

<!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIh2xe4jnpk"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have entered wrong yotube URL. you need to embedd the video...

```
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PIh2xe4jnpk"></iframe>
</div>
<!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PIh2xe4jnpk"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh gosh you're right, I didn't notice hahaha, many many thanks!